# Loading assets doesn't work right after turning on device, but works after. What's going on?

Tags: java, android, media-player

My application loads and plays a video as an asset through the Media Player class. But I've noticed that whenever I turn off my device (a Samsung Galaxy Tab), turn it back on and run the application the video doesn't load. But if I wait a few minutes and re-run my application it works.

What could be going on at the device start up that would make loading my video as an asset file fail? I say "fail", but I don't see any obvious errors in the log.

I know that on start up, the device has to through steps like finding media. So maybe playback doesn't work until that's done. How do I find out that everything is finished and ready before I know I can play a video?

Answer (score 0):

You can try registering a `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest with intent filter [`android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED). It requires the permission [`android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED)

Comment: Maybe the `mediaserver` process was not ready at the moment the activity was launched? Anyway, tell us if it fixes it.